# nobody has RFT6455 websocket server written in C language?

Tags: html, websocket

I'm looking for c language server of websocket version 13 RFT6455 protocol to study : )
so nobody has simplest c server or know where it is???

+
should I do decode and uncode baseon64 to implete websocket server?

Comment: See my answer to [your other websocket question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746980/hi-guys-im-trying-to-make-my-own-c-language-websocket-serverhandshaking/9748937#9748937) for where to base64 encode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not simple, but [libwebsockets](http://git.warmcat.com/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets) is currently the canonical C WebSockets library.

Comment: thank you for reply : ) I'm done to make C webSockets server program although it can handshake only!